# xmlrpc.php Returning 405 Response Code

Tags: xml-rpc

I hope someone might be able to help with this. A week ago we had a severe drop in rankings on the home page only. When I went to Google Search Console a new error was reported 2 days before the drop.
The first was xmlrpc.php was returning a 405 error and wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is returning a 400 error.

I am looking at fixing the errors now, but one advice I saw on another site was to replace the xmlrpc with one from a fresh wordpress download.
My question is, will this mess up a website?

any advice to get around the other error would also be much appreciated. Thanks

This all seems to of happened when a plugin was updated (Toolset Types) but the site is built with this so I cannot disable that particular plugin.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the requests data / response data via Developer Tools in your browser (usually F12, but depends on your browser). That might give you some indication of the direction to investigate.

*Personal Opinion*

Personally, I have disabled `xmlrpc.prg` on all of my sites. It is an easy way for a hacker to attack your site, either with a DDOS, or even a brute force attack on your login page. The `xmlrpc.prg` allows the hacker to 'stack' multiple requests into one reqeust.

In fact, I had to de-hack a site that was compromised due to an apparent `xmlrpc.prg` attack. They modified files, inserting some obfuscated code.

You might want to investigate if your site really needs to have `xmlprc.prg` enabled. You can disable it with this command in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

You can also deny access via your htaccess file:

```
# Block WordPress xmlrpc.php requests
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
# allow from xx.xx.xx.xx   #add allowed IP addresses
</Files>
```

Note that disabling `xmlrpc.prg` may cause problem with remote posting processes.